# Laptop doesn't see boot devices after HDD replacement

Tags: boot, windows, hard-drive, boot-repair

On a laptop I had HDD with Windows. Then I inserted HDD with Ubuntu. When the laptop loads it shows UEFI and there are no bootable devices.

I tried reconnecting the HDD and the battery. When I returned the HDD with Windows back - it worked. But I can load Ubuntu from a USB-stick. Maybe there are some commands that I should execute in live-usb mode ?

Comment: You should disable save boot (or set it to "other OS") in your BIOS to be able to boot other OS than Windows from HDD.

Comment: @mondjunge Tried - nothing changed.